# Defining clickable regions by (x,y) coords in javascript Phaser canvas

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, event-handling, polygons

**==The Crux==**
How do I elegantly define five equal-area clickable regions in terms of (x,y) coordinates for a pentagon?

**==The Context==**
I have a clickable sprite for a javascript game using Phaser. The sprite is shaped like a pentagon and each of the vertices defines a territory that is one-fifth of the pentagon's area. When the user clicks within the territory, the event handler calls the appropriate function for that territory and returns the (x,y) position clicked within the territory.

I am a novice javascript programmer who would like to learn how (and why) to write [elegant code](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/unix-koans/ten-thousand.html), if possible. I can do a little math. Normally, clickable regions are defined as rectangles, but this is a special case. The five-fold symmetry of the graphic is integral to the theme of the game (Five Elements Gong Fu).

What is a good way to define these clickable regions in terms of the coordinates? I feel as if there is some computer-math-formula-wizardry ( that could be thought of that would rely on the symmetry to somehow define the coordinates in an elegant way, but I haven't been able to determine one.

Additionally, the graphic is centered in a png file that is rectangular. I need to somehow translate the coordinates of the pentagon's neighborhoods to the coordinates of the canvas so that the user can feel they are clicking the appropriate region.

***edit***
**==Crappy Graphic==**
Ideally, the pentagon would be drawn symmetrically, but I just roughed this up. Like this:
[image: Pentagon]

How do I define the (x,y) coordinates of neighborhood A so that the user can click region A and it calls Function_for_region_A(handler)?

Comment: Can you help a little bit by providing some graphic/image?

Comment: Here's a demo I've setup that might help you: [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/learnjavascript/h9fhvm4v/). The idea is to use the [barycentric coordinate system](http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/GeometryPointAndTriangle3.aspx) to find if a point is inside a triangle. My demo uses the Canvas API to draw all the shapes, and also embed an image on top of the pentagon shape. I think it's a good start for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @KostasX Not only did you discover an elegant method (dividing the pentagon into five triangles is obvious once you see it), but you essentially coded all the relevant parts in jsfiddle. I would hire you if I had a software company. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anything about phaser, so here is only javascrip. You could rotate the whole canvas and reput it to it's normal angle when done. So when rotated, the regions become squares and it makes the code and programming simpler. I think you must rotate the canvas 60° to get squares, but I am not sure. I'm not sure if this is correct, so plz do not jugde me or take away points from me xD, THIS IS REALLY REALLY COMPLICATED FOR ME.Here is the code :`

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvasId").getContext("2d");
//code to draw the the pentagon here
var regionA = { //Because the canvas rotates, the x and y points change, so it must have other destination points.
   x : pointToTheLeftInRegionA.x,
   y : pointToTheLeftInRegionA.y - pointAtTopInRegionA.y / 2
}
function canvasWhenClicked(event) { //Function called when : "<canvas onclick="canvasWhenClicked(event)" ...></canvas>"
    var X = event.clientX;  //Finds x coordinates of where you clicked
    var Y = event.clientY;  //Finds x coordinates of where you clicked
    ctx.rotate(60 * Math.PI / 180);
    if (X > regionA.x && X < regionA.width + regioA.x) { //Sees if the X where clicked is bigger than regionA's X and smaller than regionA X + width
       if (Y > regionA.y && Y < regionA.height + regionA.y) { //Sees if the Y where clicked is bigger than regionA's Y and smaller than regionA X + height
          Function_for_region_A(handler); //If clicked in box, call function
       }
    }
    ctx.rotate((360 - 60) * Math.PI / 180); //rotate the canvas back
}
```